# Help Me Solve Font Sizing Issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, rendering

There's been this ongoing display issue my team has been having with the font size rendering larger than it should within the product. We've been having a heck of time pinpointing what it is.

Here's a screenshot of a before and after shot:
http://quickbase.intuit.com/images/font-issue.gif

Notice that in the before, it looks like the browser zoom has been zoomed in - but it hasn't. The only cure is to refresh the page and it goes away.

Other things you should know:
- We've tried comparing the source of the html/css when the bug happens and when it doesn't. They're the same.
- It happens in FF and Safari. (I rarely use IE so I can't confirm it happens there).
- It's intermittent. You have to click around a lot and load a bunch of pages before it happens it again.
- Firebug is showing all of the elements on the page as loading fully (no partial content)

Any ideas on what it could be?

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with quickbase (and other aps) in the past.  I've always put it down to some external resource not loading (css or javascript). I feel confident in that since I know that one of the aps it happens on isn't that complicated.

---

A little more information:

I noticed that your body class is being created dynamically, and one of the styles thrown in there is "stdBody". I suspect that that part of your script is messing up somewhere. Maybe a server cache somewhere? When I go in and kill the 70% font-size, I'm getting your before styling.

Comment: Yea - caching is turned off. I thought that might be the case as well, but that's a pretty difficult issue to troubleshoot. Perhaps I can try a different way to apply the stdBody class.

Answer (score 0):

Run some validator on your code, perhaps there's some error in the HTML code or in a script that enlarges the font.